# Is there a standard way in Epicor to log messages on the client side

Tags: c#, logging, epicorerp

I know how to log messages from a BPM, but at the moment I am working on some client side code (Form customisation), and it would be very helpful if I could write to a log.

Is this a feature that Epicor supports out the box, or do I have to use a third party tool like NLog or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Generally for almost everything I have wanted to log in the client it has been much quicker to get at it via the debugger or using trace.

When I have wanted to write things out, I have generally just used a combination of System.IO and System.Xml.Serialization to write out to disk what I need. Pretty much all the data in Epicor can be serialized/deserialized.

That said, if you do want to do some custom client side logging, I believe there is a copy of log4net.dll in with the client install. I have used it for some non-customization type processes. I wouldn't necessarily say it is easy to implement, but it is certainly not rocket surgery. I ended up writing a small wrapper class for it to define log levels and manage the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of Epicor is limited, but I get messages on the client-side using the Epicor System Monitor. The messages are generated by the SystemTaskAgent. So maybe you can figure out a way to push messages through that mechanism. Don't know if that helps.